# Best way to update a (subset of) object A with values from object B (Same Type)

Tags: typescript

I have a type which has many properties.

```
type X = {
   prop1 : number,
   prop2 : number,
   ...
   propN : number
}
```

I have a set of `currentValues` and `baseValues`.  They are always the same type X.  I want to calculate *some* of `currentValues` values from `baseValues` but never all of them.  Right now I'm doing this with keyof to iterate on the union of X's keys, then and a regex ‍♂️ filter to narrow to relevant keys.

```
      let x : keyof X;
        for( x in (this.currentValues)){
            if( aRegExForValidKeys.test(x))
                this.currentValues[m] = someFunction( this.baseValues[m] , someVar );
        }
```

#### Q: What is the proper technique here?

---

###### *aside*:

I was thinking I could create a type Y like this and use a `for...in` loop on it

```
type Y = Pick<X, "prop1" | "prop2">
```

but was actually getting errors that sounded like Y was not narrow enough

Comment: it seems adding `[key:string]:number` in the type declaration is a way, but I still cannot find an answer as to why string unions that represent existing keys will not work

Answer (score 1):

> They are always the same type X. I want to calculate some of
> currentValues values from baseValues but never all of them. I was
> thinking I could create a type Y like this and use a for...in loop on
> it

That's not right. Changing it's type to `Y` is just you telling to change its "**Type definitions**" - there's nothing changed in the runtime value **at all**. In order to exclude some keys from `currentValues`, you will need to add a condition for that.

> Right now I'm doing this with keyof to iterate on the union of X's
> keys, then and a regex ‍♂️ filter to narrow to relevant keys.

That's one way to go, you were on the right path here.

Another way you could do it;

```
type X = {
  prop1 : number,
  prop2 : number,
  propN : number
};
type CurrentValueType = { [key in keyof X]: any };

const currentValues = this.currentValues as CurrentValueType;

const whitelistKeys = ['prop1', 'prop2'];

for (const key in currentValues) {
  if (whitelistKeys.indexOf(key) >= 0) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: ok  I see. 
...as for using type Y with the `Pick`... i wasn't trying to transform A to a new type. I was trying to convince compiler that if i used a set of keys from Y; and if Y's keys were based on a pick of X; and A is based on type X; then surely compiler could trust those keys to also be valid for A . recall, I'm using types (type aliases) not interfaces. maybe that would be a good feature for TS to have?

Comment: @gillyspy There was such discussion as I recall. But no, that's not what typescript should do and I am afraid it will never be implemented. You can create a type from your variable (which you can use to pick those keys), but not the other way around.